# Is it possible to name a thread in the Visual Studio debugger?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, debugging, ide

I'm working in C# 4.0 (winforms), debugging an application with 10+ threads.  While debugging, there is a drop down to select which thread I should be debugging (only accessible during a breakpoint).

These show up as "Win32 Thread", "Worker Thread", "RPC Callback Thread", etc...

I'd love to name them from within my code.  I'm running all my threads via background workers.

Edit: my solution.  This may not work 100% of the time, but it does exactly what it needs to.  If the labels are wrong in some case, thats OK in the context I'm working with.

At every backgroundworker's *_dowork event, I put the following line of code in:

```
ReportData.TrySetCurrentThreadName(String.Format("{0}.{1}", MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType, MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name));
```

Which is...

```
  public static void TrySetCurrentThreadName(String threadName)
  {
     if (System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.Name == null)
     {
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.Name = threadName;
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well you can use the [Thread.Name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.name.aspx) property, but you can only write to it once - so when you *create* the thread, give it an appropriate name.

Comment: API [`CreateThread`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682453.aspx) in Windows doesn't allow names. I assume the names in .NET are just placeholders? If they are, they could have been read/write (though I can't think of a use-case for renaming a thread).

Comment: Since I'm using BackgroundWorkers to run all my multithreading, is that a safe action?  I would assume that it may re-use threads as it needs, so only naming once may not be acceptable.

Comment: @Abel: .NET threads are not necessarily thin wrappers around WinAPI threads.

Comment: @greggorob64: Do you *have* to use `BackgroundWorker` rather than starting your own threads? If you want the thread to have a name, I suspect you'll have to start it yourself.

Comment: I've ran a few quick experiments, and my backgroundworker.dowork is setting Thread.Name as "FunctionName"+(staticcounter)++.  After running it 50 times, I got no exceptions.  When I attached the debugger and examined the thread names, only "49" and "50" where in the list.  Either the first 48 "died" and disappeared from my thread list, or it allowed itself to be overwritten.

Comment: @JonSkeet, unfortunately, the backgroundworkers are currently not possible to change. The scale of the change is not worth it for the "cosmetic benefit" of having thread names show up in the debugger, which is just a time saving device.

Answer (score 1):

```
Thread.CurrentThread.Name = "Give your name here";
```

Comment: Will throw `System.InvalidOperationException` when the name was already set.